# CakePHP update record from API call

Tags: php, api, cakephp, sql-update

I'm trying to add an API call for an application that will update the record of a particular building. This is the simple version of it, but it does not seem to be doing any thing (including erroring). What am I missing? Any thoughts are appreciated!

The url that is calling the API method:
`http://example.com/api/request/UpdateBuilding/<token>/156/The%20Atticus%Building/120%20Finch%20Street%20Monroeville/50830`

The method source code:

```
private function UpdateBuilding() {     
    $buildingId=@$this->params['pass'][2];
    $name=@$this -> params['pass'][3];
    $address=@$this -> params['pass'][4];
    $zip=@$this -> params['pass'][5];

    $this->data=array(
        "id"=>$buildingId,
        "name"=>$name,
        "address"=>$address,
        "zip_code"=>$zip
    );

    $this->Building->save($this->data);
}
```

Comment: you should use an isset() instead of all those suppressing @'s in your code. It's cleaner and makes more sense. Blocking errors may lead into unexpected behavior.
What you also could do to make your code more readable is using named parameters as described here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/947/Named-parameters (assuming that you are still using 1.3 by your syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments in this thread: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314632/save-returning-false-but-with-no-error-in-cakephp`, I used `debug($this->ModelName->invalidFields());`  to determine that there were two fields missing. Glad to know!