# Can't update a field by array data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp. I'm trying to update a field record but one field is not updating. What is wrong with my code? Code is below:

```html
if (!empty($data['psetting_id'])) {
  $data = array('id' => $data['id'], 'psetting_id' => $data['psetting_id'], 'custom_package_id' => 0);
}
$this->PackageCustomer->save($data);
```

When I print this array then view information below :

[image]

From this array the following field is being updated:
  custom_package_id
but psetting_id is not being updated.

Comment: you should check step by step debugging. specially before save command

Comment: Try to check using debug($this->validationErrors); die(); if action save fails, as suggested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314865/421063 Then update the OP with the output